# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION

Tags: properties

I get the following error message when running a job based on a groovy file "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION for class: lang.Binding at getVariable", please advise

hope to get an advice how to modify the groovy file, as I saw such advices for similar exceptions; but these advices were different from each other according to the missing property